# ClassPathXmlApplicationContext Not found

Tags: spring, classnotfoundexception, classnotfound

Getting Exception for ClassPathXmlApplicationContext Not found exception. 
I have added core spring dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi i was facing this issue but resolved it by using Dependency:

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

You can change the version accordingly.